# Docker COPY succeeds but there is no file upon inspection

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I put this line in my Docker file.

```
COPY gorpyter_tutorial.ipynb /usr/local/man
```

This message is displayed on `build`.

```
Step 4/10 : COPY gorpyter_tutorial.ipynb /usr/local/man
 ---> b4b53dc0c6b1
```

But when I `exec... /bin/bash` into the container it is not in the expect directory or any other directory.

```sh
$ cd ~
$ find * gorpyter_tutorial.ipynb

'find: ‘gorpyter_tutorial.ipynb’: No such file or directory'
```

My other changes like setting environment variables and installing libraries are working successfully though.

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest

MAINTAINER layne sadler <lsadler@wuxinextcode.com>

USER root

COPY gorpyter_tutorial.ipynb /usr/local/man

RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y

ENV JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes
ENV NOTEBOOK_DIR=/usr/local/man
ENV R_HOME=/opt/conda/lib/R
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

WORKDIR /usr/local/man

# https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  jupyter:
    image: "hashrocketsyntax/gorpyter:skyline"
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - /Users/laynesadler/Desktop/notebooks:/usr/local/man
```

Am I not allowed to copy into the `/usr/local/man` as it is a volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile contains instructions to create an **image**. After the image is built, the **image can be run as a container**.

A volume is attached when *launching containers*.

It thus makes no sense to use Dockerfile instructions to copy a file into a volume **while building an image**. So, a volume only **exists after container startup**.

> Volumes are the preferred way to persist data in Docker containers and services. Some use cases for volumes include:
>
> Sharing data among multiple running containers. If you don’t explicitly create it, a volume is created the first time it is mounted into a container. When that container stops or is removed, the volume still exists. Multiple containers can mount the same volume simultaneously, either read-write or read-only. Volumes are only removed when you explicitly remove them.
>
> When the Docker host is not guaranteed to have a given directory or file structure. Volumes help you decouple the configuration of the Docker host from the container runtime.
>
> When you want to store your container’s data on a remote host or a cloud provider, rather than locally.
>
> When you need to back up, restore, or migrate data from one Docker host to another, volumes are a better choice. You can stop containers using the volume, then back up the volume’s directory (such as /var/lib/docker/volumes/).

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/storage/)

Comment: Thank you. Upon invesitigation... if you COPY files into the same VOLUME that you mount in docker-compose.yml, then the files will disappear at runtime.

Comment: Yes, you need to think it as a "virtual" volume to be mounted.